# Listview OnItemClick and button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my application I have listview. Each listview's item has button.

When I press onItemClick button's state change too.

Here is my code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_gl"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_gl"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_unselect"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/prod_button"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/prod_button"/>
</selector>
```

and this is my listview item button

```
 <Button
                        android:id="@+id/productAdd"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        style="@style/button_style"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_indicator"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

I don't understand what I did wrong here, and why always button get changed his state when I press on Listview's item?

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing out that upon list item selection your button changes state and this behavior is undesired. I think that this may be caused by this line:

```
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ph_prod_button_gl"/>
```

If the item is selected also the contained button is selected.
Have you tried removing it?
Let me know if this works.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works well in my listview. No undesired status change. In my test the button starts off with focused="false" item and if i press it, it matches state_pressed="true". If i click in the item i get no changes. Can you post the button style and the context of the button too?

Comment: the strange thing is that it is not working only in older devices like Nexus s (2.3.7)